# Optimizing React App’s Size In Production with Amcharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, amcharts, amcharts4

I'm using `amcharts` (amcharts4) with React app(generated using cra).

I was able to successfully exclude few dependencies(cpexcel, canvg, pdfmake) using `webpack Externals` in `webpack.config` file `(node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js)` like this:

```js
externals: [
      function (context, request, callback) {
      if (/cpexcel|canvg|pdfmake/.test(request)) {
        return callback(null, "commonjs " + request);
      }
      callback();
    }]
```

I also want to exclude the `xlsx` dependency, but it throws error while building with this configuration:

```js
externals: [
      function (context, request, callback) {
      if (/xlsx|canvg|pdfmake/.test(request)) {
        return callback(null, "commonjs " + request);
      }
      callback();
    }],
```

Error is:

```
$ react-scripts build
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

chunk runtime-main [entry]
Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

I'm not using any csv feature of `amcharts`.
[image: source-map-explorer]

Is there any other possible way to exclude `xlsx` (without using standalone library and removing manually) in `amcharts` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was because of `react-chartjs-2`. I was trying few chart libraries and I forgot to remove the library.

Successfully excluded the `xlsx` library.

```js
externals: [
      function (context, request, callback) {
      if (/xlsx|canvg|pdfmake/.test(request)) {
        return callback(null, "commonjs " + request);
      }
      callback();
    }],
```